# Tycho tests failing due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/AssertionFailedError

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, junit4, tycho

I am completely flummoxed and flabbergasted by this one.  In my understanding, it **should** work, but I don't know why.

I have a tycho build that just runs a few tests in an eclipse worksbench.  However, all of my tests fail with this kind of exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/AssertionFailedError
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.test.AbstractCommandTest.tearDown(AbstractCommandTest.java:112)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:140)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.tests.util.ManagedTestSuite.run(ManagedTestSuite.java:231)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:123)
at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:84)
at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.AbstractUITestApplication$1.run(AbstractUITestApplication.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3529)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3182)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.UITestApplication.runApplication(UITestApplication.java:31)
at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.AbstractUITestApplication.run(AbstractUITestApplication.java:114)
at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.UITestApplication.start(UITestApplication.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 54 more
```

This doesn't make sense to me.  `org.junit` and `org.junit4` are dependencies of the bundle running the tests as well as the bundle that contains `AbstractCommandTest`.  These tests pass when run inside my workspace, so why is it that maven/tycho cannot load the junit classes?

I'm happy to provide more information like a link to the github repo if that will help.

---

EDIT:  Providing more details

The github repo is here: https://github.com/grails/grails-sts-tests

You can see that it is a simple, single plugin that just runs some tests.  The test suite is made up of tests coming from plugins in other repositories that are specified as dependencies.  Note that the test plugins that are located in other repositories are run on another CI server and do not have the NoClassDefFoundError problem.  I've taken a look at the other CI server and don't notice anything different (unfortunately, this CI server is not publicly accessible, so I can't share a link to it).

A hudson build job showing the problem is here: http://hudson.grails.org/job/grails-sts-tests-2.0.x/17/console

Comment: Please, try to provide some more details about how did you configure Tycho/the test projects. In my experience, build errors in Tycho are more often that not caused by some minor misunderstanding of its default plug-in model.

Comment: Thanks.  Providing more details.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown whenever a dependency of the class is not found or cannot be loaded. Since you say the plugins compile on another CI server, I would suspect that it runs on a different JVM version. Can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: Is it happening while testing the whole project or one class?

Comment: @melix I added the full stack trace.  It's not very interesting.  The JUnit class is on the classpath somwwhere, but the classloader for the test bundle is not able to load it.  This is an OSGi problem and I am not sure why this is happening since my test bundles require the JUnit bundles.

Comment: @Doszi89 This is happening for every JUnit test that I run and it is always throwing the error on the same class.

Answer (score 2):

We had very similar problems. The cause is that the junit framework tries to create and use a custom classloader, and that doesn't play well with the eclipse plugin classloaders. There are some guidelines to running unit tests with Tycho that we follow now.

1. Your unit tests are in a plugin fragment. The unit test fragment has the dependency on JUnit.
2. your pom should turn off the use of the system class loader for the unit tests. This is what causes the junit test classes to be lost.
3. Then you use the same packaging as a standard plugin (eclipse-plugin, to be exact).

So a simple POM (for us) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>master</artifactId>
    <groupId>mgws</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../mgws/build-environment/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>mgws</groupId>
  <artifactId>mgws.spectral.test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>JUnitTest</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
              <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This makes the unit test framework use the eclipse plugin classloaders and now it finds all the classes.

Comment: I'm surprised by this.  Why are you not running your tests using the tycho-surefire-plugin?  The configuration section for the tycho-surefire-plugin looks quite different.  But, thanks for the useSystemClassLoader hint.  I am trying that right now.

Comment: We had a requirement to run the unit tests as non-plugin tests. I don't remember why, it's been several years.

Comment: I had to add this to the configuration to make the tests run:
    <testClassesDirectory>target/classes</testClassesDirectory>

Answer (score 1):

Still no one able to answer the question, but thanks for the information even if it hasn't been directly useful.

I have made some progress.  I have 45 out of my 60 tests passing now.  I simply added some extra dependencies like this in tycho-surefire-pluign configuration area:

```
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
                        <artifactId>org.junit</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    ...
                </dependencies>
```

Unfortunately, the remaining tests are still failing with the same `NoClassDefFoundError`.  It's possible that I need to add some more dependencies and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would do to check:

1. Check the cause of NoClassDefFoundError. There are various reasons like UnSupportedClassVersionError and ExceptionINinitializationError being most common.
2. Use the JVM option `-verbose:class` to get the classloading logs and check classes are getting loaded from expected artifacts for required classes.

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundError is thrown by OSGi because the class cannot be found in the classloader for the test bundle.  I just added the -verbose:class option and I am going through the logs.  Nothing too interesting so far...

Answer (score 0):

I suffered through a similar issue running junit tests on an Android project which depended on a few 3rd party jars, and the issue ended up being that one of the dependent jars was built with jdk v1.5 and everything else was 1.6. I updated the one library to a newer version which was built with 1.6 and then the error went away.

Don't know if its the same issue, or if you can configure tycho or update it, but it might be worth a look.....